# Minimum bounding rectangle of an array

Tags: python, algorithm, extract

The problem is the following: a matrix with only 0s and 1s is provided (example below), I need to be able to identify (and extract eventually) the minimum bounding rectangle to the 1s.
e.g.

```
0  0 0 0 0  0  
0 [0 0 1 0] 0  
0 [0 1 1 0] 0  
0 [1 0 0 0] 0  
0 [0 0 0 1] 0  
0  0 0 0 0  0
```

I am not able to come up with a good solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post what you have done so far, some code. Also specify a programming language in your tags for attracting more people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main idea is:

- Start with a candidate box being the whole array.
- While the first or the last row or the first or the last column of the candidate box only contains zeroes, shrink the box by that row or column.
- If you can't shrink any more following that rule, you have the bounding box (maybe 0 by 0 elements, if there was no 1 in the array).

Answer (score 1):

```
m = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
min_col = max_col = min_row = max_row = None
for i, row in enumerate(m):
    for j, col in enumerate(row):
        if col:
            if min_row is None:
                min_row = i
            if min_col is None or min_col > j:
                min_col = j
            if max_row is None or max_row < i:
                max_row = i
            if max_col is None or max_col < j:
                max_col = j
print('starting row = %s' % min_row)
print('starting column = %s' % min_col)
print('ending row = %s' % max_row)
print('ending column = %s' % max_col)
```

This outputs:

```
starting row = 1
starting column = 1
ending row = 4
ending column = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
# Find all positions where arr value is 1
pos_list = [(i,j) for i,r in enumerate(arr) for j,e in enumerate(r) if e]
# [(1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 4)]

# Get min of all (x, y) values as start_pos and max of all (x, y) values as end_pos
x_pos, y_pos = zip(*[(i,j) for i,r in enumerate(arr) for j,e in enumerate(r) if e])
start_pos, end_pos = (min(x_pos), min(y_pos)), (max(x_pos), max(y_pos))
print (start_pos, end_pos)
# (1, 1), (4, 4)
```

Eliminate all blank rows, transpose array (by zipping it), again eliminate all rows, transpose it back again, to get the smallest sub array for original array that fits all 1's

```
sub_arr = list(zip(*[r for r in zip(*[r for r in arr if any(r)]) if any(r)]))
print (sub_arr)
# [(0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)]
```